# On Oracle Apex, how to create multiple database Schema's on the same Workspace using the free version

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Using the free package on Oracle Apex (Oracle Application Express), using the online version (not on-premises), hosted on:

https://apex.oracle.com/

Is it possible to create multiple database schema's in a database? This is for the FREE online version.

For example, create a table called `[finance].[t_users]`, where the schema is called `[finance]`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbp/manage-database-schema-association-apex.html), this is possible but maybe the free version does not allow this ?

Multiple schemas are essential as the database grows, requiring a separation of logical namespaces via schemas.

Comment: Although apex.oracle.com is free, it is not for production use (not sure if that's what you're doing, just a heads up). However, Oracle now has a free tier in its public cloud which can be used for production: http://oracle.com/cloud/free That includes two free databases which include APEX. You will get a lot more space too! Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOn3HdoSs6s

Comment: If my answer below helped you to solve your problem, I would appreciate if you can mark the answer as correct. Thanks! @Rax [HOW DO I ACCEPT AN ANSWER](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You can create another schema under the same workspace by raising a Service Request.

[image]

Provide the schema name and submit the request.

[image]
Once approved you can see multiple schema's under the Same workspace. Something like below.

[image]